Our site logo's broken :(
As of now, our site's logo in the mid-top bar is broken, both on Crypto.Meta.SE and on Crypto.SE.
Here's a picture of either site's logo:


This bug was confirmed in private by a co-mod of mine and by Maeher in The Side Channel, so it really seems to be a more global issue.
Can we please have this fixed?
As a reminder, it should look like this:



If you came here and asked yourself "why is this featured?", then I tell you that this was done so that you're not like "is this just me?".

Not sure if I should go <sarcasm>That new logo design is a bit too minimal for my taste.</sarcasm> or rather opt in for a meme. – Jokes aside, it’s indeed not as it should be.

No reaction to this at all?

@Maeher I just pinged a CM on it, so they are aware of it now.

If this is a feature, rather than a bug, do we all get new t-shirts?

@SEJPM When can we start offering a bounty on questions like these? I know, style transitions that nobody really wants to implement. But 6 days is a long time for the main logo. This is the first thing people see when visiting this site!

@MaartenBodewes You can't start bounties on child meta sites. But the design team is aware of this.

@animuson Thanks for the feedback. Highly appreciate it!

We just optimized a bunch of our SVG images, and it introduced a few artifacts. I've replaced the Cryptography sprites. It should be fixed in the next build.

Thanks for fixing this, looks fine now! I'll get out my centimeter in a minute :P

Looks perfect. Thanks for the efforts and quick fix!
